# How to deserialize properties written with ContractResolver ResolvePropertyName

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm trying to write a space-saving JSON serialization by using a custom ContractResolver that overrides the `ResolvePropertyName` method to yield shorter property names:

```
internal class MapContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override string ResolvePropertyName(string propertyName)
    {
        return GetShortNameOf(propertyName);
    }
}
```

Now, I have to inverse this for the deserialization. I have a method called `GetPropertyName(string shortName)` however I don't know where to call it. Is there an appropriate method I could override?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay. The trick is to not override `ResolvePropertyName` but instead to override `CreateProperty` which is called both for serialization and deserialization like this:

```
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        JsonProperty jsonProperty = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
        jsonProperty.PropertyName = GetShortNameOf(jsonProperty.PropertyName);
        return jsonProperty;
    }
```

Note: `jsonProperty.UnderlyingName` will still hold the full property name.